# Is there a method called after viewDidLayoutSubviews?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I need to add a CALayer to a UILabel, but only after the UILabel has changed its frame. The UILabel changes its frame in the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method, and if I add the CALayer there, it will create multiple instances of the CALayers since `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called multiple times. I've tried removing all of the CALayers before adding a new one, but sometimes that removes the text as well. I've just used `self.eventAttending!.layer.sublayers = nil` to set the sublayers to null.

So, I think the simplest answer to my issue is to simply add the CALayer after the frame has been adjusted in the `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, which brings me to my question: What method is called after `viewDidLayoutSubviews`?

Comment: I believe `viewDidAppear` occurs after `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

Comment: That will appear *after* the view appeared. Maybe too late. And it can get called multiple times as well.

Comment: Sameet, did you find a solution? I am having the same trouble. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27627938/avcapturevideopreviewlayer-in-a-scroll-view-while-using-auto-layouts

Comment: viewDidAppear will do the job for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no method that is *always* called after `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, which is called during the creation process but can also be called when things happen to your view like adding a new subview.

Your best bet is to create a reference variable to your layer so can either remove it, adjust it as necessary, or just check if your reference variance is not nil and then don't recreate it.

Comment: Although my design may not be perfect and Eiko's answer is probably more helpful for others, your suggestion was more helpful to me in solving my current issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Add the layer or subview if you need to and when you need to. Let layoutSubviews do its job.

If you can only add your layer after the layout process finished, you are doing the wrong thing during the layout phase.

Fix your design, it's the best and easiest way.

Comment: I have a question about your answer. I have a UIImageView on my VC's root view and I want to make a http request to load an image with image view's size. But it seems image view's size is not fixed in viewDidAppear yet. Which timing should I be using to make sure to get image view's size?